# Using loop index to give names and wild card symbols for cbind

Tags: r, loops, indexing, wildcard

I would like to run a loop that saves one separate result element for each loop iteration. This element should contain the loop index in the name, so that it does not get overwritten.

My problem is that I can't find out how to use the loop index in the element names' when the elements should get saved.

Here is the code I would like to get to run:

```
data.frame1 <- data.frame(x=c(1:10))

for (i in 1:5) {
  res.data.frame[i] <- data.frame1 * i


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution using the assign function:

```
data.frame1 <- data.frame(x=c(1:10))

for (i in 1:5) {
  assign(paste("res.data.frame", i, sep = ""), data.frame1 * i)    
}
```